# Benchmarking curl vs wget vs python-request library

Tags: curl, python-requests, wget

I was working on some challenge on WebGoat where I need to conduct a brute force request attack to the server. I have written a script in bash (using curl). However, I found a similar script online that is written in python and when I ran it, the python script was able to run the attack at a much faster speed.

Thus, I came up with a little benchmarking experiment. I will use the following script to make request to that container and benchmark the performance with `time`.

```sh
$ cat test_curl
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for i in {1..1000}; do
    curl -s -o /dev/null 'http://localhost:8080/WebGoat/login'
done
```

```sh
$ cat test_wget
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for i in {1..1000}; do
    wget -q -O /dev/null 'http://localhost:8080/WebGoat/login'
done
```

```sh
$ cat test_request
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests

for i in range(1, 1001):
    requests.get('http://localhost:8080/WebGoat/login')
```

```sh
$ time ./test_request
real    0m4.240s
user    0m2.136s
sys     0m0.125s
```

```sh
$ time ./test_wget
real    0m4.623s
user    0m1.752s
sys     0m0.731s
```

```sh
$ time ./test_curl
real    0m17.907s
user    0m7.420s
sys     0m3.692s
```

In conclusion, should i avoid using `curl` when I am making lots of requests? And it seems that `python-requests` stands out as the winner here. Can someone validate my conclusion? Did I miss out something?

Does anyone know the huge variation in performance in `curl` and `wget`? 
It seems that a similar experiment was conducted between `curl` and `wget` [here](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2016-06/0143.html) fews years back. But there is still a stark difference in performance.

Answer (score 1):

Strange that python is faster than curl on your machine.
On my macbook pro :

```
time ./test_curl
./test_curl  15.78s user 8.04s system 39% cpu 1:00.09 total
time ./test_request
./test_request  39.26s user 2.58s system 10% cpu 6:29.79 total
```